# Como separar itens de um array de objetos por tipos dinâmicos?

Tags: javascript, array

Como faço para separar itens de um `array` de objetos por um tipo que cada objeto tem? Lembrando que os tipos são conhecidos apenas em tempo de execução.

Por exemplo:

```
[
    {
        id:1,
        name: maria,
        tipo: pessoa
    },
    {
        id:1,
        name: joao,
        tipo: pessoa
    }
]
```

e poder imprimir dessa forma:

```
pessoa: maria
        joao
```

e assim por diante, na imagem mostra um `json` de como estão meus dados.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer imprimir ou separar cada posição em um variável? ficou confusa sua pergunta?

Comment: Então o que acontece, eu tenho esse array de objeto onde dentro eu posso ter varios objetos com varios tipos, eu atualmento estou exibindo ele com um .map, porem agora preciso que imprima o tipo acima e os itens daquele tipo abaixo

Comment: você tem que passar a variável que eu acho que é um objeto de array de objetos, estou supondo?

Comment: isso, mesmo, mais nao faço ideia como fazer isso, voce teria alguma ideia?

Comment: cola uma imagem do console.log em cima da variavel

Comment: amigo to sem entender, atualmente faço assim , array.map(item => (<Text>{item.name}</Text>)), como eu faria agora?

Comment: não está tendo resultado satisfatório fazendo assim? se está usando `React`? poderia colocar todo o código?

Comment: eu tenho sucesso com esse codigo entendeu? so queria listar agora de um novo jeito, colocando acima o nome do tipo como expliquei na pergunta ai em cima

Comment: Você está em duvida então em apresentação do resultado? e quer mostrar todos os nomes um debaixo do outro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o 'filter' para verificar cada item, e escolher por tipo (ou outra propriedade)
Você deve passar uma callback, que irá verificar cada elemento do array. Se essa callback retornar true, o elemento será retornado em um novo array.

```js
let array = [
    {
        id:1,
        name: 'maria da silva',
        tipo: 'pessoa'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name: 'joao',
        tipo: 'pessoa'
    },
    {
        id:3,
        name: 'maria de souza',
        tipo: 'pessoa'
    },
    {
        id:4,
        name: 'toto',
        tipo: 'animal'
    }
]

// 'i' é o ítem, pode ter qualquer nome
let pessoas = array.filter((i) =>{
        return i.tipo == 'pessoa'
    })


let animais = array.filter((i) => {
        return i.tipo == 'animal'
    })

let marias = array.filter((i) => {
        return i.name.indexOf('maria') >= 0;
})
   
console.log(pessoas);

/* resultado do console.log acima
[{
  id: 1,
  name: "maria da silva",
  tipo: "pessoa"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "joao",
  tipo: "pessoa"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "maria de souza",
  tipo: "pessoa"
}] */

console.log(animais);

/* resultado do console.log acima
[{
  id: 4,
  name: "toto",
  tipo: "animal"
}]
*/

console.log(marias)

/* [{
  id: 1,
  name: "maria da silva",
  tipo: "pessoa"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "maria de souza",
  tipo: "pessoa"
}] */


let a =[{
        id:1,
        name: 'maria da silva',
        tipo: 'personagem'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name: 'joao',
        tipo: 'pessoa'
    },
    {
        id:3,
        name: 'maria de souza',
        tipo: 'pessoa'
    },
    {
        id:4,
        name: 'toto',
        tipo: 'animal'
    }
]


//acrescentado após comentário explicando que os tipos são dinâmicos

let tipos = a.map((i) => {
    return i.tipo;
})

console.log (tipos)

/*
resultado do console.log acima
["personagem", "pessoa", "pessoa", "animal"]
 */
 
r = {};
  
  
tipos.forEach((t) => {
  r[t] = a.filter((i)=>{
    return i.tipo == t;
  })
});


console.log(r);
/* 
resultado, separado por tipo
{
  animal: [{
  id: 4,
  name: "toto",
  tipo: "animal"
}],
  personagem: [{
  id: 1,
  name: "maria da silva",
  tipo: "personagem"
}],
  pessoa: [{
  id: 2,
  name: "joao",
  tipo: "pessoa"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "maria de souza",
  tipo: "pessoa"
}]
}
*/
```

Comment: so porque eu nao posso fazer desse jeito porque eu nao vou saber que tipo vai vim no array, quantos tipos vai vim, entao eu nao tenho como controlar que tipo vai vim

Comment: Você pode sim... Você pode por exemplo, extrair todos os tipos antes, depois passar por eles.. Dá uma olhada aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpvkt1qw/

Comment: Coloquei o mesmo código na resposta, para deixar as duas estratégias disponíveis.

Comment: show, funcionoou

Comment: Que bom... Lembre-se de aceitar a resposta ;)

Answer (score 2):

Tem que refazer o objeto

```js
var a = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'maria',
    tipo: 'pessoa',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'joao',
    tipo: 'pessoa',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'tareco',
    tipo: 'animal',
  },
];
var b ={};
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i].tipo) {
    if (!b[a[i].tipo]) {
      
      b[a[i].tipo] = [];
    }
    b[a[i].tipo].push(a[i]);
  }
}
console.log(b);
```

Comment: funcionou amigo dessa forma

Comment: Obrigado @Joycinha. Por favor, pode marcar como a resposta está correta.